# Hide button in UICollectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uicollectionview

I am programmatically creating cells and adding a delete button to each one of them. The problem is that I'd like to toggle their .hidden state. The idea is to have an edit button that toggles all of the button's state at the same time. Maybe I am going about this the wrong way?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("verticalCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RACollectionViewCell
    let slide = panelSlides[indexPath.row]
    cell.slideData = slide
    cell.slideImageView.setImageWithUrl(NSURL(string: IMAGE_URL + slide.imageName + ".jpg")!)
    cell.setNeedsLayout()

    let image = UIImage(named: "ic_close") as UIImage?
    var deleteButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(-25, -25, 100, 100)
    deleteButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    deleteButton.addTarget(self,action:#selector(deleteCell), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    deleteButton.hidden = editOn
    cell.addSubview(deleteButton)
    return cell
}


@IBAction func EditButtonTap(sender: AnyObject) {
    editOn = !editOn
    sidePanelCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Where's your attempt to toggle the `hidden` property of the buttons? What help are you actually looking for?

Comment: I tried by using a tag for the buttons but that didn't work. I am not sure how to reference all of those buttons.

Comment: How about having a boolean variable that your cells read and set their hidden property to, i.e. deleteButton.hidden = myBool. And everytime it's set reload visible cells.

Comment: ^^ Just tried this, it successfully toggles them on, but doesn't remove it... haha

Comment: @UlisesGiacoman Could we see your deleteCell function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is iterate over all of your data by index and then call `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` on your `UICollectionView` for each index. Then you can take that existing cell, cast it to your specific type `as? RACollectionViewCell` an then set the button hidden values this way.

Example (apologies i'm not in xcode to verify this precisely right now but this is the gist):

```
for (index, data) in myDataArray.enumerated() {
   let cell = collectionView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(row: index, section: 0)) as? RACollectionViewCell
   cell?.deleteButton.hidden = false
}
```

You probably also need some sort of `isEditing` Boolean variable in your view controller that keeps track of the fact that you are in an editing state so that as you scroll, newly configured cells continue to display with/without the button. You are going to need your existing code above as well to make sure it continues to work as scrolling occurs. Instead of creating a new delete button every time, you should put the button in your storyboard and set up a reference too and then you can just use something like `cell.deleteButton.hidden = !isEditing`